# Can android be able to detect if more than 1 NFC tag exists? (Updated on 23-Sept)

Tags: android, nfc

I've come into a problem.

It is well written over the internet on how to detect and write on 1 `NDEF` tag for android.
The `NfcF.get(tag)` can only return the most recent tag.

How about if it is possible to know if 2 NFC tags overlapping each other and presented to the NFC on the phone?

It seems on the api on google tells me that only 1 NFC tag can be returned at any instance.

((Update))
Seems that there exists some mechanism on collision detection at some level below application level. Would it be possible for the application level to access the event of collision detection? There is no need for me to distinguish what tags exist under the NFC field. What I am interested is the co-existence of 2 or more tags under the NFC field so I can pull out trigger on application.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't, in general phones only support writing one tag at a time. If you place two NFC tags on top of each other, the phone might either recognize only one tag, or not detect the tags at all.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible.

In order to do this you'd have to be able edit/monitor the collision avoidance protocol of the NFC chip. Collision avoidance is (very roughly) where the chip sends out a 'Hello' to all tags in its RF field and they respond with a 'Hey'. The chip then chooses out of the tags that responded to it which one to talk to.

Unfortunately there's no way as an Android developer to see which tags have responded and then manually choose out of them, Android picks one and gives it to you. You can see the collision avoidance bit of the NFC protocol with various desktop readers however and read multiple tags.